# derby Syntax error: Encountered EOF Next Value sequence

Tags: sequence, derby

Working with embedded database derby version 10.12.1.1.
I have created a sequence successfully as below

> CREATE SEQUENCE BUCKET_SEQ AS BIGINT START WITH 1000;

But when trying to get next value using

> SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR BUCKET_SEQ

below error encountered:

> `Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 40.`

Please suggest any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `SELECT` from something, and the something has to be some sort of a table.

The simplest thing to do is to use the SQL `VALUES` keyword, which makes an (unnamed, temporary) table for you.

You then give the table a name, and the table's column a name, and select the value from that:

```
select t from ( values next value for bucket_seq ) s( t);
T
--------------------
1000
```

There are other syntax forms possible, but this is a simple one that you can use.